# Jekyll / Liquid include files dynamically

Tags: include, jekyll, liquid

currently I'm working on a new site with Jekyll and have some kind of problem there. I have a layout page, where I can define the background image with variables from each page.

Layout:

```
class="background background-{{ page.header_bg }}"
```

Page:

```
---
header_bg: storm
---
```

But now I want to include some file dynamically, depending on the variable value. Well, I can do it with some if or case statements, but actually I want to do something like

```
{% include page.header_bg %}
```

But this does not work, because Jekyll is looking for a file, that is called "page.header_bg" and not the value.

Can some one help me please?

Answer (score 12):

According [to the docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes), you need to put the variable name inside additional `{{ }}`.

Quote from the link:

> #### ProTip™: Use variables as file name
>
> The name of the file you wish to embed can be literal (as in the
>   example above), or you can use a variable, using liquid-like variable
>   syntax as in  `{% include {{my_variable}} %}`.

Comment: Can I load data file from `_data` using same syntax: `{% for item in site.data[page.menu] %}`

Comment: How does one pass an argument with this metthod? I tried `{% include {{path_to_file}} {{arguments}} %}` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is 6 years old but here's a clear answer for posterity. You need to `assign` `page.header_bg` to a variable first and then use the variable in the `include` statement.

```
{% assign headerBg = page.header_bg %}

{% include headerBg %}
```

You will get an error `Liquid Exception: Invalid syntax for include tag` if you attempt to use `page.header_bg` directly in the `include` statement.